# Python function to find # of unique words/total words not working...why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unique

Why is this code not working?

```
def hapax_legomana_ratio(text):
''' Return the hapax_legomana ratio for this text.
This ratio is the number of words that occur exactly once divided
by the total number of words.
text is a list of strings each ending in \n.
At least one line in text contains a word.'''

uniquewords=dict()
words=0
for line in text:
    line=line.strip().split()
    for word in line:
        words+=1
        if word in words:
            uniquewords[word]-=1
        else:
            uniquewords[word]=1
HLR=len(uniquewords)/words

print (HLR)
```

When I test it, it gives me the wrong answer. For example, when there are 3 unique words in a string of 9, it gives me 0.20454545454545456 instead of .33333.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of fallacies in your code. I think there is a typo in the line `if word in words` because it should be `uniquewords` (dict) instead of just `words` (which is the count).

More on, your text that is being supplied should be split into lines & should be list of such lines. I would rather recommend to do this

```
for line in text.splitlines():
```

So that you don't have to worry for the text being passed to be a `list`.

Also, you are doing `len(uniquewords)` which is wrong since you store **all** the words in the dict irrespective of being unique. The word's uniqueness is given by the `value` obtained from the dict by passing the word as the `key`, i.e. 1 or -1. Thus, you should iterate over the dict's items & count the keys with value as `1`.

Also, you are not taking care of punctuation characters! Suppose this is the text

```
This is a test,
yes it is a test.
```

Notice how the `test,` & the `test.` would be differently stored in the words `dict`?

The slightly corrected code is as follows.

```
def hapax_legomana_ratio(text):
    ''' Return the hapax_legomana ratio for this text.
    This ratio is the number of words that occur exactly once divided
    by the total number of words.
    text is a list of strings each ending in \n.
    At least one line in text contains a word.'''

    uniquewords = dict()
    words = 0
    for line in text:
        line = line.strip().split()
        for word in line:
            words += 1
            word = word.replace(',', '').strip()
            if word in uniquewords:
                uniquewords[word] -= 1
            else:
                uniquewords[word] = 1

    unique_count = 0
    for each in uniquewords:
        if uniquewords[each] == 1:
            unique_count += 1
    HLR = unique_count/words

    print (HLR)
```

Finally, if this is a really big project &/or you would require this in the future too, I would rather recommend using the `collection.Counter` library to do all this instead of doing all this.

Comment: Using the same test, this method gave me 0.045454545454545456.

Comment: Sorry, thought the splitlines part was a substitute for the line.strip and split. Worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To find the ratio: number of unique words to total number of words in a text:

```
from collections import Counter

def hapax_legomana_ratio(text):
    words = text.split() # a word is anything separated by a whitespace
    return sum(count == 1 for count in Counter(words).values()) / len(words)
```

It assumes that `text` is a string. If instead you have a list of lines then you could get the `words` list as follows:

```
words = [word for line in all_lines for word in line.split()]
```